# Qual a diferença entre os componentes TSQLDataSet, TSQLQuery, TSQLTable e TSQLSimpleDataSet?

Tags: delphi

No Delphi, seguindo a linha dos componentes `TTable` e `TQuery` existentes na paleta de componentes `BDE` temos também componentes similares na paleta `dbExpress` que são o `TSQLQuery` e o `TSQLTable`, e ainda temos os componentes `TSQLDataSet` e o `TSQLSimpleDataSet`.

Vejo por exemplo que o `TSQLSimpleDataSet` incorpora propriedades e métodos como as de um `ClientDataSet`, o `CreateDataSet`, o `Data` e o `Delta`, como exemplo.
Com certeza tais componentes existem porque um fim específico existe para cada um deles e não podem todos simplesmente ter a mesma finalidade.

Acredito que esse é um fundamento básico mas de grande importância para os programadores Delphi

Entao:
**Qual a diferença entre esses componentes? Uma aplicação prática seria interessante!**
**Para ser claro, estou perguntando sobre cada componente mencionado. Não pela paleta `BDE` ou a `dbExpress`.**

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Qual a razão do TSimpleDataSet?**

O conjunto TSQLQuery + TDataSetProvider + TClientDataSet possui muitos recursos e é amplamente utilizado mas, existem casos de aplicações cliente servidor onde o desenvolvedor quer utilizar algo mais simples, algo como um TSimpleDataSet que na verdade é o conjunto acima citado incorporado em um único componente.

**E quanto ao TSQLQuery e o TSQLDataSet?**

Como pode ser visto neste **[link](http://www.mail-archive.com/delphi-br@yahoogrupos.com.br/msg43789.html)**, o Bruno Lichot (que já foi um evangelista da Embarcadero no Brasil) explica que o TSQLQuery foi mandido por compatibilidade e que o TSQLDataSet é a sua evolução, fazendo as mesmas coisas, mas possuindo mais recursos. Ambos são os objetos de consultas ao banco de dados.

**E o TSQLTable?**

É uma ferramenta de consulta ao banco de dados mais simples, que não faz consultas personalidas no banco, somente o carregamento do conteúdo de uma tabela, algo como um 'SELECT * FROM tabela'

Comment: Mas sabe dizer se existe ***AINDA*** casos específicos para o qual cada um deles são mais rexomendados? +1 pela boa resposta. Obrigado!

Comment: @TiagoPSilva Não sei se existe um caso de mais recomendados, acredito que, de acordo com o que eles fazem, se adaptam melhor ao que o programador quer fazer mas o `TSimpleDataSet `é mais utilizado em aplicações cliente/servidor sem datamodules e enquanto o `TSQLQuery/TSQLDataSet` é mantido no DataModule para que várias telas utilizem ele conectando seus providers ou clientdatasets e o `TTable` quando se quer listar todo o conteúdo da tabela

Answer (score 3):

O [**BDE**](http://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Borland_Database_Engine)(*Borland DataBase Engine*) foi utilizado em versões anteriores do Delphi. Embora não seja obsoleto(*ainda?!*), é aconselhável migrar para o *dbExpress* ou [**FireDac**](http://www.embarcadero.com/br/products/rad-studio/firedac-faq).

O [**dbExpress**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DbExpress) foi introduzido a partir da versão *6* do Delphi para substituir o *BDE*.

Atualmente o **FireDAC**(*se não me engano está disponível a partir do XE3*) surgiu para substituir o *dbExpress*. O *FireDAC* é sem dúvida uma solução melhor, sem dúvida vale a pena migrar suas aplicações de *BDE* ou *dbExpress* para **FireDAC**.

[**Este artigo**](http://www.andreanolanusse.com/pt/firedac-anydac-o-que-isso-representa-para-os-desenvolvedores-delphi-e-c/) comenta algo sobre o assunto que deve ser de interesse para você.

Comment: O conteúdo é bom! +1 Mas deve ser pela hora que você estava postando, pois eu perguntei a diferença entre o componentes do dbExpress, o que vai refletir a diferença básica entre os outros também . (rs) ;) A não ser que não fui claro ou que você quis complementar o assunto.

Comment: Até editei a pergunta para ficar mais claro. E obrigado pela resposta.